# mysql slow query optimisation with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

i have site with opencart 1.5, mysql 5.7 and slow query like:

```
SELECT a.attribute_id, ad.name as attribute_name, pa.text, ag.attribute_group_id, agd.name as attribute_group_name FROM product_attribute pa
    LEFT JOIN attribute a ON (pa.attribute_id = a.attribute_id)
    LEFT JOIN attribute_description ad ON (a.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id)
    LEFT JOIN attribute_group ag ON (a.attribute_group_id = ag.attribute_group_id)
    LEFT JOIN attribute_group_description agd ON (ag.attribute_group_id = agd.attribute_group_id)
    WHERE pa.product_id = 1029
            AND ad.language_id = agd.language_id
            AND pa.language_id = agd.language_id
            AND agd.language_id = 1
    ORDER BY ag.sort_order, agd.name, a.sort_order, ad.name
```

Explain give me:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                    | key                | key_len | ref                                     | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | agd   | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY                          | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                    |   20 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ag    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY            | 4       | my_shop.agd.attribute_group_id     |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,attribute_group_id       | attribute_group_id | 4       | my_shop.agd.attribute_group_id     |    3 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pa    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,attribute_id,language_id | PRIMARY            | 12      | const,my_shop.a.attribute_id,const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ad    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY            | 8       | my_shop.a.attribute_id,const       |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

How i can change this query to use indexes?
Real data in tables and structure for example lower:
How i can change this query to use indexes?
Real data in tables and structure for example lower:
How i can change this query to use indexes?
Real data in tables and structure for example lower:

```
CREATE TABLE `attribute` (
  `attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `attribute` (`attribute_id`, `attribute_group_id`, `sort_order`) VALUES
(22, 7, 120),
(21, 7, 100),
(23, 7, 110),
(20, 7, 90),
(19, 7, 80),
(18, 7, 70),
(17, 7, 60),
(16, 7, 40),
(15, 7, 30),
(14, 7, 20),
(13, 7, 15),
(12, 7, 10),
(24, 7, 130),
(25, 7, 150),
(26, 7, 160),
(27, 7, 170),
(28, 7, 180),
(29, 7, 190),
(30, 7, 200),
(31, 7, 210),
(32, 7, 140),
(33, 7, 50),
(34, 7, 85),
(35, 7, 87),
(36, 7, 88),
(37, 7, 85),
(38, 7, 135);


CREATE TABLE `attribute_description` (
  `attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `attribute_description` (`attribute_id`, `language_id`, `name`) VALUES
(16, 2, 'Толщина корпуса, мм.'),
(14, 2, 'Гарантия'),
(13, 1, 'Product code'),
(17, 3, 'Dial Colour'),
(15, 1, 'Case width approx., mm.'),
(14, 3, 'Guarantee'),
(13, 2, 'Шифр'),
(17, 4, 'Dial Colour'),
(16, 1, 'Case depth approx., mm'),
(15, 2, 'Ширина корпуса, мм.'),
(14, 4, 'Guarantee'),
(13, 3, 'Product code'),
(14, 1, 'Guarantee'),
(13, 4, 'Product code'),
(12, 3, 'Model'),
(12, 2, 'Модель'),
(12, 1, 'Model'),
(17, 2, 'Цвет циферблата'),
(17, 1, 'Dial Colour'),
(18, 2, 'Люминофор'),
(18, 3, 'Luminous'),
(18, 1, 'Luminous'),
(19, 4, 'Case material'),
(19, 3, 'Case material'),
(19, 2, 'Корпус'),
(19, 1, 'Case material'),
(20, 4, 'Bezel material'),
(20, 3, 'Bezel material'),
(20, 2, 'Безель'),
(20, 1, 'Bezel material'),
(21, 3, 'Lens'),
(21, 2, 'Стекло'),
(21, 1, 'Lens'),
(22, 3, 'Strap type'),
(22, 2, 'Ремешок'),
(22, 1, 'Strap type'),
(23, 4, 'Water Resistant'),
(23, 2, 'Водонепроницаемые до:'),
(23, 3, 'Water Resistant'),
(23, 1, 'Water Resistant'),
(24, 3, 'Strap width'),
(24, 2, 'Ширина ремешка:'),
(24, 1, 'Strap width'),
(25, 3, 'Movement'),
(25, 2, 'Механизм'),
(25, 1, 'Movement'),
(26, 3, 'Automatic winding'),
(26, 2, 'Автоматический завод'),
(26, 1, 'Automatic winding'),
(27, 2, 'Ручной завод'),
(27, 3, 'Manual winding'),
(27, 1, 'Manual winding'),
(28, 3, 'Jewels'),
(28, 2, 'Количество камней'),
(28, 1, 'Jewels'),
(29, 3, 'Accuracy'),
(29, 2, 'Точность при температуре 20±5°С'),
(29, 1, 'Accuracy'),
(30, 3, 'Power reserve'),
(30, 2, 'Запас хода при полном заводе, не менее'),
(30, 1, 'Power reserve'),
(31, 4, 'Average term of service'),
(31, 3, 'Average term of service'),
(31, 2, 'Срок службы'),
(31, 1, 'Average term of service'),
(32, 3, 'Strap color'),
(32, 2, 'Цвет ремешка'),
(32, 1, 'Strap color'),
(33, 2, 'Длина (от лапок до лапок) мм.'),
(12, 4, 'Model'),
(33, 1, 'Lug to lug size, mm.'),
(18, 4, 'Luminous'),
(21, 4, 'Lens'),
(22, 4, 'Strap type'),
(24, 4, 'Strap width'),
(32, 4, 'Strap color'),
(25, 4, 'Movement'),
(26, 4, 'Automatic winding'),
(27, 4, 'Manual winding'),
(28, 4, 'Jewels'),
(29, 4, 'Accuracy'),
(30, 4, 'Power reserve'),
(16, 3, 'Case depth approx., mm'),
(16, 4, 'Case depth approx., mm'),
(15, 3, 'Case width approx., mm.'),
(15, 4, 'Case width approx., mm.'),
(33, 3, 'Lug to lug size, mm.'),
(33, 4, 'Lug to lug size, mm.'),
(34, 1, 'Dial'),
(34, 2, 'Циферблат'),
(34, 3, 'Dial'),
(34, 4, 'Dial'),
(35, 1, 'Hands'),
(35, 2, 'Стрелки'),
(35, 3, 'Hands'),
(35, 4, 'Hands'),
(36, 1, 'Crown'),
(36, 2, 'Головка'),
(36, 3, 'Crown'),
(36, 4, 'Crown'),
(37, 1, 'Caseback'),
(37, 2, 'Задняя крышка'),
(37, 3, 'Caseback'),
(37, 4, 'Caseback'),
(38, 1, 'Wrist size, mm'),
(38, 2, 'Максимальный объем запястья,мм'),
(38, 3, 'Handgelenkgröße, mm'),
(38, 4, 'Tamaño de la muñeca, mm');


CREATE TABLE `attribute_group` (
  `attribute_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `attribute_group` (`attribute_group_id`, `sort_order`) VALUES
(3, 2),
(4, 1),
(5, 3),
(6, 4),
(7, 0);


CREATE TABLE `attribute_group_description` (
  `attribute_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `attribute_group_description` (`attribute_group_id`, `language_id`, `name`) VALUES
(3, 1, 'Память'),
(4, 1, 'Technical'),
(5, 1, 'Материнская плата'),
(6, 1, 'Процессор'),
(3, 2, 'Memory'),
(4, 2, 'Technical'),
(5, 2, 'Motherboard'),
(6, 2, 'Processor'),
(3, 3, 'Memory'),
(4, 3, 'Technical'),
(5, 3, 'Motherboard'),
(6, 3, 'Processor'),
(3, 4, 'Memory'),
(4, 4, 'Technical'),
(5, 4, 'Motherboard'),
(6, 4, 'Processor'),
(7, 1, 'Specification'),
(7, 2, 'Характеристики'),
(7, 3, 'Specification'),
(7, 4, 'Specification');

ALTER TABLE `attribute`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_id`),
  ADD KEY `attribute_group_id` (`attribute_group_id`),
  ADD KEY `sort_order` (`sort_order`);

ALTER TABLE `attribute_description`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_id`,`language_id`),
  ADD KEY `name` (`name`);

ALTER TABLE `attribute_group`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_group_id`),
  ADD KEY `sort_order` (`sort_order`);

ALTER TABLE `attribute_group_description`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_group_id`,`language_id`),
  ADD KEY `name` (`name`);


ALTER TABLE `attribute`
  MODIFY `attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=39;

ALTER TABLE `attribute_group`
  MODIFY `attribute_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: you can try this way `... LEFT JOIN attribute_group_description agd use index (PRIMARY) ...`

Comment: We'd need some sample data to understand.  I manage over 30 opencart sites and ran this query against a handful of the ones that are heavy on product attributes.  none of them gave the explain results yours did.  `PRIMARY` key was used for the join in every case.

Comment: i added dump of this tables in first post

Answer (score 0):

Remove unuseful () in ON clause
and (not for performance but for sql correct use)  don't use column related  to left join table otherwise the work as inner join
You have literal value the use it

```
  SELECT a.attribute_id, ad.name as attribute_name, pa.text, ag.attribute_group_id, agd.name as attribute_group_name 
  FROM product_attribute pa
    LEFT JOIN attribute a ON pa.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
    LEFT JOIN attribute_description ad ON a.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id 
                and ad.language_id  = 1
    LEFT JOIN attribute_group ag ON a.attribute_group_id = ag.attribute_group_id 
    LEFT JOIN attribute_group_description agd ON ag.attribute_group_id = agd.attribute_group_id 
                AND agd.language_id = 1
    WHERE pa.product_id = 1029 
    AND pa.language_id = 1 
    ORDER BY ag.sort_order, agd.name, a.sort_order, ad.name
```

Comment: With a`LEFT JOIN`, if want filter the left table is done in the `WHERE`, filter the right table is done in the `ON`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  correct  ..  is what i mean with involved  in LEFT  JOIN  .. the from table can use where the table in LEFT JOJ must use ON clause

Comment: Sorry that comment was mean for the OP. I think that is an easy way to remember it.

Comment: don't sorry .. your comment are always  good comments ..  so  i appreciated  your contribute  .. and hope the OP too ..